# How to calculate nutrition fact?

Tags: micronutrients, nutrition, labeling, brands, guidelines

I'm not sure i'm posting on the right place and I don't really know what it is called.

I just wondering. How the cuurent food company calculated the nutrition information of they food?
In my opinion:
example, not all Orange will contain 2mg of Vitamin C, it should depends on the size of the Orange, where the tree grew, how old is the Orange, how much is the weight, how much part of it get into the product and etc.

But why if I buy 2 same product from the same company it has the same nutrition(written on the nutrition fact)?
It should not the same on the nutrition count. Right?
Anyone can answer?
Sorry for my English, hope you still can get what I mean.